# WebGL: When using THREE.MeshFaceMaterial, every face has different orientation

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am trying to make a building in WebGL using THREE.js framework.

I am new to 3D graphics and I have never worked with any other tools (DX, OpenGL, ...)

I am trying to create a building in my scene using following code.

```
var windowTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./images/windowside.png');

windowTexture.repeat.set(1,2);

var windowMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: windowTexture});

var buildingMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial([
    windowMaterial,
    windowMaterial,
    windowMaterial,
    windowMaterial,
    topMaterial,
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffff00})
]);
```

Then making a BoxGeography

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.3, 0.3, 1);
var building = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, buildingMaterial);
```

And finally adding it to scene.
I have not included code I do not consider important.

Now, it displays the Box just fine with a texture on it. But the texture is all wrong. It looks like this
[image]

Appearently, each face has different orientation.

Question is - am i using the right technique for a Box with multiple textures? (top and bottom are different)

Is there a better way?

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need change order of texture. Some like this:

```
var buildingMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial([
    windowMaterial,
    windowMaterial,
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff00ff}),
    windowMaterial,    
    windowMaterial
]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nnphw58s/